# Find two generators of a $\Bbb{Q}[x]$-module $\Bbb{Q}^5$.

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

Let $T$ be a linear transformation on $\Bbb{Q}^5$ which is defined by 
$$T(v)=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 0 & -4 & 0\\
3 & 1 & 2 & -4 & -3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
-2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4
\end{pmatrix}v.$$
We know that we can view $\Bbb{Q}^5$ as a $\Bbb{Q}[x]$-module where $x\cdot v\stackrel{\text{def.}}{=}T(v)$.
I want to find **two** generators of this $\Bbb{Q}[x]$-module $\Bbb{Q}^5$.
That is, 
find $v_1, v_2\in \Bbb{Q}^5$ such that $\{f(T)v_1+g(T)v_2\mid f(x), g(x)\in \Bbb{Q}[x]\}=\Bbb{Q}^5$.

Thanks.

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: I have tried some easy cases. Like $v_1=(1, 0, 0, 0, 0)^t$, $v_2=(0, 1, 0, 0, 0)^t$ or $v_1=(1, 0, 0, 1, 0)^t$, $v_2=(0, 1, 0, 0, 0)^t$. But these vectors can't generate the $\Bbb{Q}[x]$-module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M$ is similar to the matrix

$$ J = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
$$

hence, it has minimal polynomial $(x-1)(x-2)^3$ and characteristic polynomial $(x-1)^2(x-2)^3$. So, as a $\mathbb{Q}[x]$-module,

$$\mathbb{Q}^5 \cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x-1) \oplus \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x-1)(x-2)^3 .$$

For $J$, a choice of two generators could be $(1,0,0,0,1)^t$ and $(0,1,0,0,0)^t$. I leave that for you to check, and how to get the generators for $M$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But $(x-2)(1, 0, 0, 0, 1)^t=(0, 1, 0, 0, 0)^t$. I don't know how to get the generators for $M$ with **minimal cardinality**. In my textbook (Goodman's **Algebra**), he determined the generators $\{e_1, ..., e_5\}$ of $V=\Bbb{Q}^5$  and the generators $\{f_1, ..., f_5\}$ of free $\Bbb{Q}[x]$-module $F=\Bbb{Q}[x]^5$ **first**. Then defined $\Phi:F\to V$ by $\Phi(\sum_i h_i(x)f_i)=\sum_i h_i(T)e_i$.

Comment: Then he found a basis $\{y_1, ..., y_5\}$ for $F$ and a basis $\{y_1, y_2, y_3, a_1(x)y_4, a_2(x)y_5\}$ for $\ker{\Phi}$ with invariant factor $a_1(x), a_2(x)$. I have no idea how to find a generating set of $\Bbb{Q}[x]$-module  $\Bbb{Q}^5$ with minimal cardinality.

Comment: It appears to me that (for the $\mathbb{Q}[x]$-module coming from $J$) we have $(x−2)(1,0,0,0,1)^t=(J−2)(1,0,0,0,1)^t=(-1,0,0,1,0)$. Anyway, do you know how to find the invariant factors?

Comment: If you don't, I know it is described in Dummit and Foote in good detail. I'm not familiar with Goodman's Algebra so I don't know off-hand how to make an answer which complements his material.

Comment: Here is a quick version of the procedure: Diagonalize $xI-M$ over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Track the row operations in a matrix $P$, so that $P^{-1}MP$ is in rational canonical form, and one easily reads off a minimal generating set. From there, use $P$ to obtain the minimal generating set for $M$.

Comment: I know that how to find the invariant factors.
(Give me some time to make sure the generating set of $\Bbb{Q}[x]$-module with respect to $T$ is the same as with resepect to $J$.)
The minimal generating set which is easily read are $1+\langle -1+x\rangle$ and $1+\langle (-2+x)^3(-1+x)\rangle$.
But I don't know what is the correspondent of these vectors in the $\Bbb{Q}[x]$-module $\Bbb{Q}^5$.

Comment: The generating sets are *not* the same. They are related by some change of basis. One way to find them is to find an element in the kernel of $(T-2)^3$ which is not in the kernel of $(T-2)^2$, and then pick any element in the kernel of $T-1$ (ie, any eigenvector with eigenvalue 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Find the rational canonical form basis $\{v_1, ~v_2, ~T(v_2), ~T^2(v_2), ~T^3(v_2)\}$ for the $\Bbb{Q}$-vector space $\Bbb{Q}^5$.
Then $\{v_1, v_2\}$ is a generating set for the $\Bbb{Q}[x]$-module $\Bbb{Q}^5$.